# MMO game server multi server exchange data

Tags: architecture

I am always thing how to design a high performance game server support millions of hot user online and play together.

My architecture:

```
Master server:
   receive client connection
   base on user id
   dispatch to slave servers
   client connect to slave server again.

Slave server:
   load user profile from data server, and won't load again before user disconnect.
   *broadcast new events to users in the same room/channel/nearby*
```

So, my question is, when I want to broadcast new events to users, but those user are not on the same server, so this event can't sent to that user directly, but has to connect another server, and send it.

More critical, when calculate user battle, the two server of the two use has to know each other information, so the two server have to load 2 user in memory, it waste too much memory.

It seems my architecture got big problem, I want to know the right architecture of a MMO game server with multi server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy! I never saw a MMO with one huge server, they always divide. Even simple games like Ogame where speed of response is not an issue, don't implement this. I guess You could use a scalable server providers like Google App Engine, but don't expect great pings!